# generate casenumber

Tags: mysql, perl

i need to generate a casenumber like this with perl and mysql:

xx-201012080001

the first part is just a couple of chars, followed by the date. the
last four digits is the problem, it should start at 0001 and increment
by one for each case. the real trouble is that it must restart at 0001
every day.

any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You're not providing enough information. Is this program a daemon/server that's constantly running? Or is it something that just runs upon request (like a script or a web page)? Are you using a shared datastore (like a database)?

Answer (score 1):

use sprintf to generate the string:

```
 my $casenumber = sprintf("%2s-%8d%04d", $twochars, $date, $increment);
```

For example, on the command line:

```
$ perl -e 'printf("%2s-%8d%04d\n", "aa", "20101211", 2);'
$ aa-201012110002
```

As for resetting your count to 1, keep a variable called $lastDate for each record in your iteration. If the $lastDate != $currentDate, you reset your counter to 1.

For example:

```
# assumes @records contain arrayrefs with relevant info from mysql
# also assumes the data is sorted by date.
my $count = 1;
my $lastDate;
my $currentDate;
for my $record (@records)
{
   my $twochars    = $record->[0];
   my $currentDate = $record->[1];
   if($currentDate != $lastDate)
   {
     $count = 1;
   }
   my $casenumber  = sprintf("%2s-%8d%04d", $twochars, $currentDate, $count++);
   $lastDate = $currentDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a query like this:

```
select casenr from cases where casenr like ? order by 1 desc limit 1
```

where the `?` is the prefix for today ("xx-20101208").

This should give you the last casenr for today or `NULL`, then just increment the suffix or set it to `0001`.